# Schema object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, properties, export, schema

I'm a learning coder trying to understand some sample code from a Q&A app

On the server-side code, the `Question` object has a property called `answers`:

```
var Question = new Schema({
    title: {type:String, required: true, trim:true},
    answers: [Answer],
    });
```

That is the only place `answers` has been defined, but it's somehow also used with `var question` in the below `for` loop:

```
var question;
var answerController = Alloy.createController('answer');

exports.setQuestion = function(c, q){
      question = c.get('questions')[q];

for(var i = 0; i < question['answers'].length; i++){
        var answer = question['answers'][i],
```

`answers` was defined through the `Question` object, how is it also being used in `question`  ?

Comment: anyone have an idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

- `c.get('questions')` returns an array of `Schema` objects.
- `question = c.get('questions')[q];` sets `question` to be one of the elements of this array, so it contains a `Schema` object.
- Every `Schema` object has two properties: `title` (which contains an object), and `answers`, which contains an array of `Answer`s.
- Therefore, `question` now refers to a `Schema` object, and you can use `question.answers` or `question['answers']` to access its `Answer` array.

What you haven't shown us is the code that calls `exports.setQuestion()`. That code must pass an object that has a `get()` method that returns an array of `Schemas`. I don't know where it gets them from. This is all part of a system that presumably keeps track of the whole list of questions that have been constructed. It's hard to explain little bits of it without all the context.

The questions you've been asking suggest a fundamental misunderstanding of the differences between variables, objects, and properties. I think you need to go back to the books and refresh your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, I'm hitting the books as we speak

Comment: Hi Barmar, so I hit the books and I have one final question. There are many Schema objects on the server, one is named `Chat` and it has the following property: `comments: [Comment]`. Does this mean if I created a new object called `chat` and called `chat = c.get('comments')[ch]`,  it will set `chat` to be on of the elements of the `[Comment]` array in `Chat`? In other words, does the `Chat` object become a template for any object that call a property belonging to `Chat`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, so I can't really answer that. All your questions seem to be very dependent on this framework, but you've never identified it (there's probably a tag for it). Schema is not a standard Javascript feature, it's something extra you're using.

Comment: I see, so how do you know that `c.get('questions')` returns an array of Schema objects?

Comment: No, because I don't know what `c` is, and I'm unfamiliar with this library. If you told us what library you're using, I could look at it to see how it works.